# calculate sum of SalesAmount of prevouis month in PowerBI using DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I spent hours trying in PowerBI to calculate the SalesAmount for Previews month but without success. I don't know what I am doing wrong!!
Here is my table:

[image]

and this my DAX function

```
PreviousMonth = CALCULATE(SUM(FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesAmount]), 
  DATEADD(FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesDate],-1,MONTH)
```

and here the result:

[image]

Why is the column empty?

Comment: Try using `PREVIOUSMONTH` function instead.

Comment: i tried but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index column with this:

`Index = COUNTROWS(Filter(FactInternetSalesTEST, FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesDate]<=EARLIER(FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesDate])))`

Then use the index to locate the earlier date value by adding another column with this:

`PreviousMonth = CALCULATE(SUMX(FactInternetSalesTEST,FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesAmount]),FILTER(FactInternetSalesTEST,FactInternetSalesTEST[Index]=EARLIER(FactInternetSalesTEST[Index])-1))`

You'll get this:

[image]

Comment: thank you Marc!  it works. but if i have multiple records for one month and i need to sum the salesAmount based on the month?

Comment: If you don't have missing months, this should work in place of what I answered before: `PreviousMonthTotalSalesAmount = CALCULATE(SUMX(FactInternetSalesTEST,FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesAmount]),FILTER(FactInternetSalesTEST,EOMONTH(FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesDate],0)=EOMONTH(EARLIER(FactInternetSalesTEST[SalesDate]),-1)))`. With this, you don't need an index.